# Programmatic name pending approval - approval duration, criteria

Tags: ibm-cloud

I tried to create a product in Partner Center and in the product dashboard, it says

"Programmatic name pending approval.

Your programmatic name is under review by IBM Cloud. You must wait until you receive approval by email to move forward with specific onboarding tasks. "

How long does this approval take and if I need to change or update, again need to wait for it?

are there any criteria for this approval?

IBM cloud -> Login (pay-as-you-go) account -> Partner Center -> My Products -> Dashboard

Also only after this approval, we will be able to deploy service broker?

Comment: Contact IBM partner support about it. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.